# Custom query for select field in Djnago admin

Tags: django, django-admin

is it possible to make custom query for that field?

I have many users, I need to filter if by group to reduce the number of choices.

[admin panel - select input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYhf8.png)

I didn't find anything except making custom query for whole models.

Any example would be enough for me.

I use build-in group model.
And let's say, I want to see in User field only from group "Director" for model below.

```
class Invitation(models.Model):
    school = models.ForeignKey(School, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

For now, I use default:
admin.site.register(Invitation)

Comment: Sure, can you share the model, admin and how you want to filter?

Comment: I updated question, I didn't customize admin.py yet. I use default User and Group models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this application-wide, you can use [**`limit_choices_to=…`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to):

```
class Invitation(models.Model):
    school = models.ForeignKey(School, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        limit_choices_to={'groups__name': 'Director'},
    )
```

if you want to only apply this in the `ModelAdmin` you can limit the queryset by overriding the [**`.formfield_for_foreignkey(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey):

```
@admin.site.register(Invitation)
class InvitationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == 'user':
            kwargs['queryset'] = User.objects.filter(groups__name='Director')
        return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).